# show nearby places in marker's infobubble with distance and duration

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My function of getting distance and duration

```
var distance_o_marker='';
var duration_to_marker='';
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
     function calcRoute_all(center,nearby)
        {
            var start = center;
        var end = nearby;


          var request = {
              origin:start,
              destination:end,
              travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
          };
          directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

                 distance_o_marker=response.routes[0].legs[0]['distance'].text;
                 duration_to_marker=response.routes[0].legs[0]['duration'].text;

            }

             });

        }
```

center is latlng for which nearby has to show

nearby is latlng of nearby place got from places api json object

giving odd results i.e. places which are close getting more distance and duration or sometimes getting undefined

sorry for my bad english

but try to give solution please

Edit:

i m getting to JSON responses,

1) nearby places

2) directionService

how to connect them

Comment: Give us some examples of the places which are giving odd results

Comment: sorry for late reply, e.g (18.516573, 73.863283) for this latlng i m trying to find nearby ATM.Result showing longer distance ATM closer and less duration. I think i m not tracing for loop properly. Could u just direct me, where i can find solution for placing nearby locations distance and duration in infobubble/infowindow of marker. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

got it result was coming asynchronously
used setTimeout();